# Regular expression extract text between double quotes with or without escape character

Tags: regex, expression

Need a regular expression to find the text between the following two examples disregarding the escaped quotes:

```
TestNode1="HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT RETURNED"
TestNode2=\"HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT RETURNED\"
```

I have this, but it is not working for escaped characters correctly:

```
"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"
```

I am expecting the following return for BOTH testnodes (1 or 2):

```
HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT RETURNED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(\\?")(.*?)\1
```

or

```
(\\\\?")(.*?)\\1
```

depends on what environment you are using...

Comment: That looks like it will do the trick! What would i need to do if i want to specify that I only want to return text from the second node? For instance: TestNode2=\"GET THIS TEXT ONLY NOT ALL MATCHES\"

Comment: Is this the only solution? Or could i specify a specific node?

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde - Yes, you can, just add `\bTestNodeName\s*=\s*` or `\\bTestNodeName\\s*=\\s*` at the beginning of the regex pattern...

Comment: Cool that will do it for me! Thanks for your help! VERY FAST RESPONSE!